# Realtime status bar view

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I have a status bar application and when I'm opening it, it shows me informations but if these informations are changing (percentage here), I don't see it directly. I must reopen it to make it shows new informations.

Here I open the app one time it's 90% :

[image: Opening the app a fist time]

Then I wait some time and reopen it, it's already 100% :

[image: Opening the app a second time]

Is there a way to show "in real time" labels and stuff in a status bar application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having come across it before:

https://github.com/adamhartford/PopStatusItem

Does quite well, appears to be thread friendly (having tested with async threads) on the popup item..
*Edit*

addition as the user needs the actual status bar Image/text updated as opposed to the popup...

```
    let sysStatusBar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_main(){
        let dele = NSApp.delegate as? AppDelegate
        dele.statusBarValue = 100.0
            // from the delegate or a singleton method, have statusbarValue observed
            //      and update the App.delegate.statusBarItem.image accordingly.
            //      make sure it happens on the main thread... then the image / text
            //      will update...
    }
```

What you're doing is updating the delegate where you've added the NSStatusBarItem and updating the image there. IN my example, I update the "statusBarValue" but if you just add a binding or an observer to the value, you can just as easily update the image.

**ONCE AGAIN** Make sure this happens on the main thread, or the UI is just going to ignore your updates. So updates from background threads etc... need to call out on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you, sweet popover but my question is about a statusbar :)

Comment: I'm confused... Your screenshots show the status bar popover? Anyway, in regards to the actual "item on the status bar, then you can still change them using treading (main thread). In short, I'll add a post...

Comment: Great, I didn't think about it, I'll test this soon as I can and I'll tell you ! :)

Comment: Just a note though.. Rather put things relating to the overall app i.e. status bar items etc.. in the Application Delegate than in some random singleton instance. Putting it in there will make sure it'll stay in sync with various other things i.e. how launchd is treating it :D